# Wann ß nach Diphthong? „heiß“ aber „Reis“

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, eszett

Wie erklärt sich, dass nach einigen Doppellauten ein ***ß*** (heiß, beiß, sch…) steht und nach anderen ein einfaches ***s*** (Eis, Mais, Kreis), obwohl es sich ebenso wie ein stimmloses s anhört?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wenn ein s im Auslaut stimmlos gesprochen wird, liegt dies an der  Auslautverhärtung des Deutschen, die auch dazu führt, dass andere Konsonanten im Auslaut härter ausgesprochen werden – so endet z. B. die Aussprache von *Wald* genauso wie die von *Halt.* Wenn nun Begungsformen oder andere Ableitungen eines Wortes existieren, in denen der entsprechende Konsonant stimmhaft ausgesprochen wird (weil er nicht mehr im Auslaut steht), wird auch im Auslaut der Buchstabe benutzt, der normalerweise für den entsprechenden stimmhaften Konsonanten steht. Hier wird also mit der Phonetik der Rechtschreibung gebrochen um Konsistenz zu gewährleisten, da sonst *der Walt,* aber *die Wälder* geschrieben würde.

Wenn ein Wort also auf einen stimmlosen Konsonanten endet, zu dem im Deutschen ein stimmhaftes Gegenüber existiert, kann man also (in den allermeisten Fällen) die Rechtschreibung bestimmen, indem man sich die Aussprache von Beugunsgformen des Wortes vor Ohren führt, in denen der entsprechende Konsonant nicht mehr im Auslaut steht.

In den Beispielen also:

> *Eis* wegen *des Eises* oder *eisig*
>   *Mais* wegen *des Maises*
>   *Kreis* wegen *des Kreises, die Kreise* oder *kreisen*
>   *heiß* wegen *heißer*
>   *beiß* wegen *beißen*
>   *scheiß* wegen *scheißen*

(Ganz analog zu: *Wald* wegen *Wälder, Halt* wegen *halten,* usw.)

Comment: +1 weil: sach ich doch.

Answer (score -2):

Heißer, beißen, scheißen vs. eisig, Maises (gen.), Kreise.

Comment: um. You mind to explain that? Currently this is just a List of the same words as Verbs / in Plural.

Comment: Die Diskrepanz zwischen Anspruch und Qualität ist hier eklatant.